# Processing pairwise comparisons

Tags: ranking

I am designing a perceptual test. I have N stimuli and K features {f1...fK}. During the test, the subject has to compare pairs of stimuli according to each feature. For example, given a pair of stimuli, the subject must say which is the most f1, which is the most f2 and so on.
What are the most used techniques to process the output of such a test?

Comment: What is the final aim of the study? Is it determine which features one of the stimulus possess more? Like stim1 is more of f1, f2 and f5, while stim2 is more f3 and f4.  Also will the subjects given stimulus only once or many times? How many subjects may be there?

Comment: Hi, since these K features {f1...fK} are subjective I want to correlate them with other M objective features {o1...oM} so that I can predict {f1...fK} given {o1...oM}. I also want to find out if there is a correlation between {f1...fk}. I don't think that a global ranking is important. I hope to collect more than 100 comparisons and it may happen that a subject performs the same comparison more than once (it is unlikely since there are a lot of stimuli and the pairs are generated randomly every time).

Comment: I believe in 'canonical correlation analysis' you can have many non-metric outcome variables with many numeric explanatory variables. For relation between f1..fk, correspondence analysis or latent structure analysis may be helpful. http://www.statmethods.net/advstats/ca.html